# Adjective meaning being difficult and requiring attention

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that qualifies an action of being difficult and requiring attention?

As an example:

> _______ spellcasting as opposed to automatic spellcasting

I can't think of anything. I am not sure if such an adjective exist. What do you think?

Comment: @puffofsmoke - (1) When writing a question, your main question shouldn't be in the title only. Before I edited your question, it read: _I can't think of anything. I am not sure if such an adjective exist. What do you think?_ That's not a good question on the Stack Exchange. Your question should be **in the question itself**, not only in the title. (2) When you are asked to clarify something, **edit** your question to add the clarification. (Users shouldn't have to read through the comments to fully understand your question.) Please remember these community norms when asking future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **fiddly** (adjective)
>    chiefly British
>    *requiring close attention to detail* [<sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiddly)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions, depending on your context:

- *Problematic* describes something that is constantly a problem.

Example: "The situation was problematic for the teachers".

- *Demanding* describes something that requires a lot of your attention.

Example: "I do a very demanding job".

- *Involved* can describe something that is difficult to understand or complicated.

Example: "My job is very involved".

- *Elaborate* describes something involving many carefully arranged parts or details; detailed and complicated in design and planning.

Example: "The instructions are extremely elaborate".

These are just a few examples. You could also use "complicated" or "complex". Perhaps use an online thesaurus to look up some synonyms of any of these suggestions.